# Equivalent conditions for continuity in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f: (X,d_{X}) \to (Y,d_{Y})$. *We have that $f$ is continuous iff for any open subset $U \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.* Prove the following are also equivalent to the definition for the continuity of $f$:

(1) For any closed subset $F \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$.

(2) For any $A \subset X$, $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$.

(3) For any $B \subset Y$, $\overline{f^{-1}({B})} \subset {f^{-1}(\overline B)}$

May someone provide some hints or tips?

I'm a little confused how to proceed. Do I assume the claim in each and work towards the definition of continuity as above? Any hints tips or clues?

Comment: Hint for the first: take an arbitrary closed set $F\subseteq Y$. You want to prove that $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$, i.e. that $(f^{-1}(F))^c$ is open in $X$. What you *know*, however, is that $F^c$ is open in $Y$, and therefore that $f^{-1}(F^c)$ is open in $X$. Can you relate $f^{-1}(F^c)$ and $(f^{-1}(F))^c$?

Comment: With the def'n $D$  of  "$f$ is continuous" , prove  $ D\to (1)\to (2)\to (3)\to D.$

Comment: Does this get me anywhere? Let $F$ be an arbitrary closed set $F \subset Y$. Thus, $F^{c}$ is open in $Y$ and so $f^{-1}(F^{c})$ is open in $X$. This implies that $f^{-1}(F^{c})^{c}$ is closed in $X$ and note that $f^{-1}(F) = f^{-1}(F^{c})^{c}$. Thus, $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$. (Where does the continuity come in?)

Comment: It was used to say that $f^{-1}(F^c)$ was open.

Comment: Ah, of course. I guess I'm trying to see where this ties into the original question, i.e. that the statement in (1) is equivalent to the continuity definition.

Comment: This shows that the original definition implies $(1)$. As @user254665 and Jack's answer suggest, the shortest way to prove all equivalences is to show that $(0) \Rightarrow (1) \Rightarrow (2) \Rightarrow (3) \Rightarrow (0) $.

Comment: Thanks. As my profile says.... I'm a lousy mathematician.

Comment: These are equivalent def'ns of continuity for any topological spaces. Two others: (with $f:X\to Y$) .(a) Whenever $ V$ is a nbhd of $f(p)$ in $Y$, there is a nbhd $U$ of $p$ in $X$ with $f(U)\subset V.\;$ (b) Each $p\in X$ has a nbhd $U$ in $X$ such that $f$ restricted to domain $U$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

If $(0)$ is the original definition,

> $(0)\implies(1):\quad f^{-1}(F)=f^{-1}(F^c)^c$

---

> $(1)\implies(2):\quad f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$ is closed and $A\subset f^{-1}(f(A))\subset  f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$.

---

> $(2)\implies(3):\quad$ Replace $A$ with $f^{-1}(B)$.

---

> $(3)\implies(1):\quad$ Replace $B$ with $F$ and remember that $\bar{F}=F$.

---

> $(1)\implies(0):\quad f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U^c)^c$